# UITableview not scrolling to the bottom cell if using UITableViewAutomaticDimension and estimatedRowHeight

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am facing a strange issue with `UITableView` if I enable the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` property.

I am fetchign some data from the server and I have kept my UITableView cell set to accept dynamic content and increase the height as per the content so far what i have done is

1. Set the number of lines of the `UILabel` to zero so that it grows as per the content
2. Added the below code inside the `viewDidLoad` method

   ```
   self.myTable.estimatedRowHeight = 200
   self.myTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   ```

Now after i fetch the data from the server i reload the table and go to the last cell of the table view but my problem is when i reload my entire table after the webservice call,

the table view animates and scrolls to the top of the screen and is not visible unless I scroll it down.

I searched and googled but i was not able to find any solution to this but if any of you have every came across this kind of situation please guide me out.

I have even added the below line of code before returning the cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but still am stuck with the same issue

```
cell.layoutSubviews()
```

here's the code which i have added to scroll to the bottom cell after the successful service call

```
self.myTable.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.myArray.count - 1, inSection: 1), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen after you reload the table?

Comment: @MikeTaverne The tableview is scrolling to the last cell but as of now i guess due to the estimatedRowHeight property its actually scrolling above and all i see is a white space, My expectations are that even if i am using estimatedRowHeight on reload the table view should display the last cell but as of now its not

Comment: Are your cells displaying variable height content OK before you reload the table? Are you sure the reload is causing the problem? Make sure you have constraints from the top of your UILabel to the top of the cell and from bottom of your UILabel to the bottom of the cell. Otherwise the cell will not expand properly.